# Common Paypal Button to accept payments

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I have e-book selling website where I used a paypal button to accept the payment. The button is created from paypal website and its code snippet is added in the form to show the button(not via api). When I set the currency of the button to USD then indian paypal users are not able to use the button. It says "Merchant Does bot accept payment in your currency". If I change it to INR then it only accepts the indian customers only.
Is there any way to accept all currencies via a common button. I means Indians could pay me in INR and Others in USD.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, separate currencies are needed due to Indian regulations, and there is no support for combining multiple currencies (and their respective amounts) within a single button, other than coding it yourself.

If you generate buttons at PayPal, you need one button for domestic payments in INR, and another button for international payments in a currency such as USD.

It's possible to make something like a dropdown or radio buttons that switch a single PayPal button between the configurations for amount1/USD and amount2/INR -- i.e., give the buyer a way to select their country and change the amount/currency based on that -- but to do that you will need to write some custom JavaScript code to make the switch.